# I need to automate running a JavaScript function on a bunch of pages, can this be done?

Tags: javascript, powershell, coldfusion, cfml

I have a lot (think tens of thousands) of cfm files where I need to add a custom attribute to the HTML tags.  I worked up a Javascript function that can update a single page. Can I open a file with Coldfusion, change it with Javascript, then save the changed file with Coldfusion?  Can you do both of these with CFScript?  Would I be better served to use Powershell?  I think you open a cfm file in Powershell something like...

```
$file = 'C:\example.cfm'
$ie = New-Object -COM 'InternetExplorer.Application'
$ie.Navigate("file://$file")
```

And my Javascript function is...

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("ThisClass");
// Loop through ThisClass elements
for (i = 0; i < x.length; ++i) 
{
  // Get the string in the HTML
  var y = x[i].innerHTML;
  // Replace spaces with underscores
  var newstring = y.replace(' ', '_');
  // Add new attribute with spaceless value
  x[i].setAttribute('ThisAttribute', newstring);
}
```

But how would do the Javascript stuff on the $ie file in Powershell?  And then save the edited file?  Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Any modern IDE can do this for you. Search for 'find and replace in files'.

Comment: You may want to rethink your development strategy because 10s of 1000s of files is completely unmanageable.

Comment: @Miguel-F I wish it was that easy.  We're not just replacing "Bob" with "Jerry".  This has to be a DOM calculation, adding an attribute where there is a certain class.  Andy - the number doesn't really matter.  Even if it's a few hundred, it's too many to manually go in and change.  Surely there's a way to do this programmatically.

Comment: I guess I don't understand your question.  You say _this has to be a DOM calculation_.  That suggests client-side calculation so you won't be able to do that on your ColdFusion server.  No powershell either.  Can you better explain what you are trying to do here?